# Cookie notification with AMP, using amp-geo and amd-consent

Tags: amp-html

I thought this would be simple. Show the 'we use cookies' warning at the bottom of the page with a close button.

Our requirements are simple, show it to everyone at least once. Straight copy with a link to the privacy policy. No cookie blocking, simple.

So does anyone have an example running that is similar that I could use as a base line? I was looking at the BBC's amp pages, but they're only showing for EU countries, and I'm looking at showing this for everyone.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're just looking to run a straight forward "we use cookies" notification with no fancy frills then `amp-user-notification` might be the route for you. We have it running on our website: https://www.craigattachments.com.

`amp-user-notification` does possess the ability to do geo targeting as well if that requirement comes up.

https://amp.dev/documentation/components/amp-user-notification

Header Script:

```
<script async custom-element="amp-user-notification" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-user-notification-0.1.js"></script>
```

Notification Code:

```
<amp-user-notification
    layout="nodisplay"
    id="amp-user-notification1"
    data-show-if-href="https://foo.com/api/show-api?timestamp=TIMESTAMP"
    data-dismiss-href="https://foo.com/api/dismissed">
    This site uses cookies to personalize content.
    <a href="">Learn more.</a>
   <button on="tap:amp-user-notification1.dismiss">I accept</button>
</amp-user-notification>
```

Comment: Thanks Craig. Your's is the first non-news site I've seen with amp. Have you noticed in increase is your search rankings with it?

Comment: I have seen a few of our deeper buried pages see a bit of a boost. But I also work a lot on our SEO to continually work on improving our search ranking. We did seem to regain a number one spot on a particular search term, though. I was more interested in the speed/optimization gains than anything as I was already pretty happy with our SEO when we started down the AMP overhaul route.